# How to open .tif file in R without RGDAL (since it is unused now)?

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have a `.tif` file and I can't open it in R.

I cannot install `rgdal` because it is not in use anymore if I am correct.
I don't find any working other way to open it.

I tried the following script :

```
library(raster) 
library(sf)

raster_name <- "C:/Users/ollivica/Downloads/CHIRP.1981.01.tif" 
raster(raster_name)

# Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
#   Cannot create RasterLayer object from this file; perhaps you need to install rgdal first
```

I need to open it as a raster but it does not work.
Sample find can be found at: https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRP/monthly/

Comment: hmm, works fine for me: `r <- raster("~/Downloads/CHIRP.1981.01.tif"); pkgVersion("raster")` (3.6.26). This appears to depend on `sp`.  Maybe you need to install a new version of `raster` ? Can you edit your question to include the results of `sessionInfo()` from a *clean* R session?

Comment: All three ([`raster`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html), [`sp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html), and [`sf`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html)) have been updated in the last couple of months (_days_, even), it seems likely this error would resolve after updating your packages.